# How to loop through all same name parent and child nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I have an XML file where I have same name nodes: Parent and child, for example:

```
<Root>
    <Field name="ID">
        <description>Test 1</description>
    </Field>
    <Field name="Period">
        <description>Test 2</description>
        <Field name="Name">
            <description>Test 3</description>
        </Field>
        <Field name="Name2">
            <description>Test 4</description>
            <Field name="address">
                <description>Test 5</description>
            </Field>
            <Field name="partyID">
                <description>Test 6</description>
                <Field name="E-ID">
                    <Field name="address">
                        <description>Test 7</description>
                    </Field>
                </Field>
            </Field>
        </Field>
    </Field>
</Root>
```

The problem is, I am not sure how deep we can have child elements with the same name:

I used template-match on top parent node:

```
<xsl:template match="Field">
<xsl:value-of select="description"/>
<xsl:for-each select="Field">
<xsl:value-of select="description"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This code is not providing me all the child node values. I am looking for a code which can loop through all same name nodes and provide value of description element.

I cannot add multiple for-each because as I said, this is unknown how many times we will have Field node inside another Field node.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursion to process all `Field` elements from the root of the tree to the leaves - for example (you did not post the expected result, so I made something up):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Field"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
    <desc>
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    </desc>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you could just select all `Field` elements regardless of their position in the tree hierarchy:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Field">
            <desc>
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </desc>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```